# how to change zoom.translateExtent after declaring zoom

Tags: d3.js

I know this...

```
var zoom=d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, Infinity]).translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]).extent([[0, 0], [width, height]]).on("zoom", zoomed);
```

...sets the extent for zoom.

When I want to change the translateExtent I tried this:

```
zoom.translateExtent([[100, 100], [width, height]]
```

but it doesn`t work.

How can I change zoom.translateExtent?

Comment: have an answer to this question ?

Answer (score -1):

```
function zoom(){
    var t=d3.event.transform;
   if(t.x<=100){
       t.x=100// when t.x <100  make t.x=100
   }else if(t.x>=200){
       t.x=200
   }
    selection.attr("transform",t);//set up your selection`s transform,lock the zoon events 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: unfortunately，my English is too poor to  make a detailed description，hope needs

Comment: Actually it won't help. It just limits transformation, but doesn't affect translate implementation of d3js, so user would need to scroll backwards much enough.